# Property list supported ObjC types

Tags: objective-c, types, plist

Is it correct to say that property list files (.plist) only handle `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate` and `NSData` (allowing to store any other type which conforms to `NSCoder`) + `NSArray` / `NSDictionary` of those types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that is pretty much the exact definition of a property list. Wikipedia has a [little table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) that explains how each class will be stored in the resulting XML file:

```
Foundation class    XML Tag                  Storage format
NSString            <string>                 UTF-8 encoded string
NSNumber            <real>, <integer>        Decimal string
NSNumber            <true />, or <false />   No data (tag only)
NSDate              <date>                   ISO 8601 formatted string
NSData              <data>                   Base64 encoded data
NSArray             <array>                  Can contain any number of child elements
NSDictionary        <dict>                   Alternating <key> tags and plist element tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Property List can only contains following types of data:

NSString
NSNumber
NSNumber 
NSDate
NSData
NSArray
NSDictionary

for more information visit: [Property List Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) or visit [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5)

You can also save other objects as NSData by serializing them