# iOS - Attempt to insert non-property list object NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

In my app, I need to save my custom `User` object `NSDictionary` in my `NSUserDefaults`. I attempt this with the following code:

```
NSDictionary *userObjectDictionary = response[@"user"];
NSLog(@"USER OBJECT:\n%@", userObjectDictionary);
[defaults setObject:userObjectDictionary forKey:@"defaultUserObjectDictionary"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This attempt crashes my app with the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
>   list object {type =
>   immutable dict, count = 10, entries =>    0 : status_id =     1 : {contents = "first_name"} = exampleFirstName    3 : id = {value = +2, type =
>   kCFNumberSInt64Type}  4 : {contents = "profile_picture"} = {contents =
>   "http://myDevServer.com/pictures/userName.jpg"}   5 :
>   last_name = exampleLastName   7 : email = {contents = "myEmail@gmail.com"}    8 : {contents = "badge_count"} = {value = +0, type =
>   kCFNumberSInt64Type}  9 : user_name = userName    10 : {contents = "phone_number"} = {contents = "0123456789"}    12 : {contents = "status_updated_at"} =
>    }  for key
>   defaultUserObjectDictionary'

This is what my `User` object dictionary looks like before I attempt to save it:

```
{
    "badge_count" = 0;
    email = "myEmail@gmail.com";
    "first_name" = exampleFirstName;
    id = 2;
    "last_name" = exampleLastName;
    "phone_number" = 0123456789;
    "profile_picture" = "http://myDevServer.com/pictures/userName.jpg";
    "status_id" = "<null>";
    "status_updated_at" = "<null>";
    "user_name" = userName;
}
```

Is it crashing because there a null values in my `User` object `NSDictionary`? I tried with a regular `NSDictionary` with dummy data with null values and it worked. If this is the problem, how to I bypass this? Sometimes my `User` object will have properties that are nullable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of your objects or keys in dictionary have class, that doesn't support property list serialization. Please, see this answer for details: [Property list supported ObjC types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295517/property-list-supported-objc-types)

I recommend to check object for key "profile_picture" - it may be NSURL.

If that doesn't help, you may use following code to identify incompatible object:

```
for (id key in userObjectDictionary) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, keyClass: %@, value: %@, valueClass: %@",
          key, NSStringFromClass([key class]),
          userObjectDictionary[key], NSStringFromClass([userObjectDictionary[key] class]));
}
```

Comment: My profile_picture, when I checked, was a string. The "status_id" and the "status_updated_at" were of class NSNull though.

Comment: So, you simply need to use another representation for "status_id" and "status_updated_at", for example `@(0)`  `NSNumber`, if you want to store them into `NSUserDefaults` :)

Comment: I marked your answer correct because it confirmed that the null values were causing the problem. I used `NSCoder` instead to store my `User` object's DATA, which didn't cause any problems with the null values.

Answer (score 3):

NSNull is acceptable in JSON (as `"<null>"`), but not listed in the property lists. So one solution is to transform the dictionary to NSData and save it. 
[image]